# SDL event sequences on wheel movement

Tags: c, event-handling, mouseevent, sdl

I am new to SDL and I am maintaining an SDL application. I want to know which (and how) events are delivered when the user play with the wheel. In my app the user modify the size of a little square on the screen using the mouse wheel. I found out the app to be very slow when the user is turning the wheel.

Basically there is one big loop

```
SDL_event event;
for(;;){
   //
   SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
   SDL_LockMutex(mymutex);

   switch(event.type){
     case SDL_CUSTOMEVENT: //handle 2 or 3 customs events
     break;
     case SDL_KEYDOWN: //handle keydown
     break;
     case SDL_VIDEOEXPOSE: //handle keydown
     break;

     case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
         switch(event.button.button){
              case SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT: 
              break;
              case SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT:
              break;
              case SDL_BUTTON_WHEELUP: <----------------------
              /**
                 Recompute the size of the box. 
                 Also, you will not believe, update
                 the whole screen by redrawing the images each time.   
              **/
              break;
              case SDL_BUTTON_WHEELDOWN:
                 //same as above
              break;

         }
     break;
   }
   //etc....
   SDL_UnlockMutex(mymutex);
}
```

So the thread executing this loop is sharing data with another thread, and because both threads can be preempted wheel events are consumed very slowly.

I want to aggregate the processing of wheel events, for instance by doing

```
while(//there are wheel down or up){
  //change direction variables
  SDL_PeepEvents(//wheel events);
}
//update the screen
```

Is there a direct way to catch wheel events with SDL_PeepEvents? I mean an alternative to peep mouse events (`SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`) and then test if the button is wheel. I saw in the [SDL 1.3 documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL-1.3-docs/SDL__events_8h.html) that there is a `SDL_MOUSEWHEEL` event type. But on the other side the . Is this available with SDL 1.2 (the version I am using). Is a `SDL_MOUSEWHEEL` and `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` both sent when the user acts with the wheel?

ps: I have no access to C++

Comment: Why are you locking `mymutex` twice?

Comment: It is meant to be an unlock

Comment: Are you allowed to use SDL_PollEvent?